# Purpose of colon in variable expansion

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I'm reviewing an old shell script. I'm not able to understand two things in it.

```
rm /data/log || true

value=$(cat /datafile)
if [ ${value: -1} ==  0 ] 
 then echo 'do'
else echo 'dont'
 fi
```

1. `value: -1` - What is this actually doing?
2. `rm /data/log || true` - What this `||true` doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rm /data/log || true` is only (in my humble experience) useful if the script is executed with `set -e`. `set -e` makes the shell exit when a command exits with an error state. The creator of the script was apparently not aware of the `-f` flag for `rm`.

`${value: -1}` is probably a typo. It should be `${value:-1}`, providing the default (1, not -1; the `-` is part of the `:-` syntax) for the variable expansion if `value` is null or not set.

If it should really be `${value: -1}`, see glenn jackman's answer for the actual meaning.

Comment: so during the execution, if there is no value assigned to `$value` or its null then number `1` will be allocation to `value`, Am I right?

Comment: Only if you remove the space between the `:` and the `-`.

Comment: This is just to say that `rm -f /data/log` would still exit with an error if `/data/log` was a directory, triggering the termination of the script under `set -e`.

Comment: It's not a typo. Or, depending on what this program is supposed to be doing with the contents of that file, it *might not* be a typo.

Comment: `${value: -1}` takes the last character of the variable contents. The full substring expansion syntax is `${var:start:length}`, but here only the starting point is given. The space is there to disambiguate it from `${value:-1}`, which would indeed be a default value expansion.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh `${value:-1}` evaluates the substitution using the `1` in the test. But it does not update the variable `value` (although there is a similar syntax that *would* do the update).

Answer (score 8):

#### `${value: -1}` expands to the **last character** of the variable contents.

`${value:-1}` is **different** from `${value: -1}`!

Referring to [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual:

1. `${value:-1}` expands to the contents of the `value` variable, or if the variable is unset or empty, to the string "1"
2. `${value: -1}` is a short form of the `${var:offset:length}` form to extract a substring of the variable contents. An offset of `-1` means "one character from the end of the string". The `:length` part is missing, so the substring is taken from the `offset` to the end of the string.

   The manual says:

   > Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least one space to avoid being confused with the ‘:-’ expansion.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Note that `${var:-default}` is a Bourne and standard `sh` operator (from the 70s), while `${var:offset:length}` is a ksh93 operator (from the 90s, now also supported by bash, zsh, mksh and busybox sh with variations, but not standard).

Comment: Hey @glenn I have a question on this, if the value is unset then how it'll take the `one character from the end of the string`

Answer (score 0):

From bash(1):
${parameter:-word}
Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word
is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

`|| true` makes sure the command returns true. `||` is a short-circuiting OR operator, if the command in front returns false, the command after it is executed and the return value used.

Comment: Thanks I think its too techical :) correct me if my understanding is wrong. So if there is no value assigned or null for $parameter then `-1` will be assigned to that parameter. Regarding `||true` still not clear, what happen the command fails? for eg: instead of  rm I use `rmmm`