# What does `:` command actually do?

Tags: shell

As far as I can tell, the `:` command does nothing.

From the `bash`'s `help :`:

```
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

Yet, I've found some people make use of the command for something else, for instance:

```
: ${var:=something}
```

My first guess is that is some "hacky" thing people do to do something.

Where can I find any documentation about it? Are there any other usage of it?

Comment: @roaima yes, it does! Not sure why searching `':' ` returns nothing from my end.

Comment: Also see [Purpose of colon in variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611213/100397)